# Finding all the 10-digit prime numbers, that have seven "7" in a row - Python

Tags: python, list, primes

so as it states in the title, I'm trying to generate a list of all the 10-digit prime numbers, that have 7x7 in a row. More precisely, I mean the numbers that can be written as follows: xxx7777777, xx7777777x, x7777777xx, 7777777xxx.

My idea is to generate a list of all this numbers, and then check which one of them is prime. The code is as follows:

```
import time
def GeneratingTable():
    A = []
    for i in range (1,10):
        for j in range (0,10):
            for k in range (0,10):
                A.append(i*1000000000+j*100000000+k*10000000+7777777)
    for i in range (1,10):
        for j in range (0,10):
            for k in range (1,10):
                A.append(i*1000000000+j*100000000+77777770+k)
    for i in range (1,10):
        for j in range (0,10):
            for k in range (1,10):
                A.append(i*1000000000+777777700+10*j+k)
    for i in range (0,10):
        for j in range (0,10):
            for k in range (1,10):
                A.append(7777777000+i*100+j*10+k)
    A = list(set(A))   # I want to get rid of duplicats here
    print(len(A))
    return A

def ifPrime(n):  # Maybe I can use more efficient algorithm? 
    Prime = 1
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n%i == 0:
            Prime = 0
            break
        i += 2
    if Prime == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0



def HowMany():
    counter = 0
    A = GeneratingTable()
    for i in range (len(A)):
        if ifPrime(A[i]):
            print(A[i])
            counter += 1
    return counter



start = time.clock()
print(HowMany())
end = time.clock()
time = end - start
print(time)
```

I am sure the number of primes I get this way is to high - it's 2115 and the number of elements in my list A is 3159. Is it a problem with my function "GeneratingTable" or checking whether the number is prime?

Comment: You can also skip a bunch using `for k in range (1,10,2)` for the ones digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your prime function is wrong, it should increase `i` by 1, not 2, or you're missing some primes.

Then you should directly add to a `set` instead of creating a list when generating table, which saves memory & CPU time (also as Chris commented, you're performing loops starting at 0 or 1, which makes you miss values, I overlooked that in my previous post, now all indices start at 0). In that case, you can simplify even more using *set comprehension*, with a 5 formulas to be able to start indices at 1,0,0 and not forget the `7777770xx` ones.

(this was tuned into the right solution with a collaborative effort with B.M. answer, which is more efficient, but also missed cases at first)

(also note that hashing integers doesn't cost much CPU time as usually the hash *is* the integer itself)

The rest seems okay. Here's my modifications:

```
import time

def GeneratingTable():
    A = {v for i in range (1,10) for j in range (0,10) for k in range (0,10)
         for v in [i*1000000000+j*100000000+k*10000000+7777777,i*1000000000+j*100000000+77777770+k,i*1000000000+777777700+10*j+k,7777777000+i*100+j*10+k,7777777000+j*10+k]}
    print(len(A))
    return A


def ifPrime(n):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

def check():
    return sorted([p for p in GeneratingTable() if ifPrime(p)])


start = time.clock()
x = check()
print(len(x),x)
end = time.clock()
time = end - start
print(time)
```

result:

> 3420
>   203 [1247777777, 1277777771, 1277777773, 1457777777, 1487777777, 1577777771, 1577777777, 1657777777, 1777777741, 1777777751, 1777777777, 1787777777, 1877777773, 1877777777, 1877777779, 1927777777, 1957777777, 2017777777, 2027777777, 2077777771, 2377777771, 2437777777, 2467777777, 2507777777, 2567777777, 2647777777, 2677777771, 2777777707, 2777777711, 2777777719, 2777777741, 2777777759, 2777777777, 2777777797, 2917777777, 3037777777, 3077777777, 3137777777, 3197777777, 3247777777, 3257777777, 3377777773, 3377777779, 3407777777, 3427777777, 3527777777, 3557777777, 3577777771, 3777777701, 3777777767, 3777777793, 3827777777, 3937777777, 3977777773, 3977777777, 4027777777, 4097777777, 4177777771, 4277777773, 4297777777, 4307777777, 4327777777, 4447777777, 4567777777, 4687777777, 4747777777, 4777777703, 4777777717, 4777777727, 4777777729, 4777777759, 4777777769, 4777777789, 4777777793, 4777777799, 4867777777, 4937777777, 4997777777, 5177777777, 5237777777, 5387777777, 5477777777, 5527777777, 5567777777, 5617777777, 5627777777, 5647777777, 5777777701, 5777777771, 5777777791, 5877777779, 6037777777, 6077777773, 6077777777, 6177777773, 6277777777, 6317777777, 6577777771, 6577777777, 6637777777, 6757777777, 6767777777, 6777777731, 6777777737, 6777777757, 6777777791, 6847777777, 6857777777, 6947777777, 6977777771, 6977777773, 7037777777, 7087777777, 7327777777, 7387777777, 7487777777, 7537777777, 7547777777, 7597777777, 7607777777, 7727777777, 7777777019, 7777777027, 7777777057, 7777777069, 7777777081, 7777777103, 7777777127, 7777777169, 7777777199, 7777777207, 7777777211, 7777777229, 7777777237, 7777777261, 7777777327, 7777777361, 7777777369, 7777777379, 7777777391, 7777777421, 7777777429, 7777777453, 7777777493, 7777777517, 7777777549, 7777777577, 7777777597, 7777777633, 7777777639, 7777777649, 7777777663, 7777777669, 7777777691, 7777777703, 7777777741, 7777777781, 7777777783, 7777777789, 7777777823, 7777777849, 7777777853, 7777777871, 7777777937, 7777777963, 7777777993, 7837777777, 7957777777, 8087777777, 8117777777, 8227777777, 8277777773, 8347777777, 8387777777, 8477777771, 8577777773, 8627777777, 8737777777, 8777777713, 8777777717, 8777777759, 8777777777, 8807777777, 8947777777, 8977777777, 9067777777, 9137777777, 9177777773, 9197777777, 9257777777, 9467777777, 9477777773, 9477777779, 9547777777, 9617777777, 9677777771, 9777777767, 9777777787, 9777777799, 9817777777, 9887777777, 9937777777, 9977777773]

note: about the efficiency of the `isPrime` function: the function is efficient to test 1 prime, but when you have 3000+ primes to test, it's best to pre-compute a prime list up to `sqrt(10**10)` (for instance using a sieve) and test against those primes. Computing the list of primes is an effort, but well made up when testing a lot of primes (like in B.M answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your function `ifPrime` thinks that all odd numbers are prime because you start at `i=2` and increment it by `2` on each loop. You therefore only check even divisors. Change `i=2` to `i=3` and you'll get 327 results after filtering. I'm not sure if that's the right answer, but the above is at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A approach with efficient tools, and [Eratosthene Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for better complexity :

```
from itertools import *

def p77():
    S=set()
    for triple in combinations_with_replacement('0123456789',3):
        quadruple=triple+('7777777',)
        for perm in permutations(quadruple):
            if perm[0]!='0': # ensure 10 digits 
                s=''.join(perm)
                S.add(int(s))

    A=np.array(list(S))       

    [eratosthene][1]=np.arange(10**5)  # sqrt(10**10)                                      
    for i in range(2,317): # sqrt(10**5)
        if eratosthene[i]>0:
            eratosthene[i*i::i]=0

    little_primes=eratosthene[eratosthene>1]                        
    for p in little_primes:
        A=A[A%p>0]

    return A
```

This gives 203 primes in 0.1 second :  ( -- for 7777777 )

```
['124--, 12--1, 12--3, 145--, 148--, 15--1, 15--7, ',
 '165--, 1--41, 1--51, 1--77, 178--, 18--3, 18--7, ',
 '18--9, 192--, 195--, 201--, 202--, 20--1, 23--1, ',
 '243--, 246--, 250--, 256--, 264--, 26--1, 2--07, ',
 '2--11, 2--19, 2--41, 2--59, 2--77, 2--97, 291--, ',
 '303--, 30--7, 313--, 319--, 324--, 325--, 33--3, ',
 '33--9, 340--, 342--, 352--, 355--, 35--1, 3--01, ',
 '3--67, 3--93, 382--, 393--, 39--3, 39--7, 402--, ',
 '409--, 41--1, 42--3, 429--, 430--, 432--, 444--, ',
 '456--, 468--, 474--, 4--03, 4--17, 4--27, 4--29, ',
 '4--59, 4--69, 4--89, 4--93, 4--99, 486--, 493--, ',
 '499--, 51--7, 523--, 538--, 54--7, 552--, 556--, ',
 '561--, 562--, 564--, 5--01, 5--71, 5--91, 58--9, ',
 '603--, 60--3, 60--7, 61--3, 62--7, 631--, 65--1, ',
 '65--7, 663--, 675--, 676--, 6--31, 6--37, 6--57, ',
 '6--91, 684--, 685--, 694--, 69--1, 69--3, 703--, ',
 '708--, 732--, 738--, 748--, 753--, 754--, 759--, ',
 '760--, 772--, --019, --027, --057, --069, --081, ',
 '--103, --127, --169, --199, --207, --211, --229, ',
 '--237, --261, --327, --361, --369, --379, --391, ',
 '--421, --429, --453, --493, --517, --549, --577, ',
 '--597, --633, --639, --649, --663, --669, --691, ',
 '--703, --741, --781, --783, --789, --823, --849, ',
 '--853, --871, --937, --963, --993, 783--, 795--, ',
 '808--, 811--, 822--, 82--3, 834--, 838--, 84--1, ',
 '85--3, 862--, 873--, 8--13, 8--17, 8--59, 8--77, ',
 '880--, 894--, 89--7, 906--, 913--, 91--3, 919--, ',
 '925--, 946--, 94--3, 94--9, 954--, 961--, 96--1, ',
 '9--67, 9--87, 9--99, 981--, 988--, 993--, 99--3   ]
```

Comment: Good approach, but I think you're missing some primes here, compared to the "bruteforce" solution.

Comment: still missing some `[1277777771, 1577777771, 1777777741, 1777777751, 1777777777, 2027777777, 2777777711, 2777777777, 3037777777, 3137777777, 3377777773, 3377777779, 3557777777, 3777777793, 3937777777, 3977777773, 4177777771, 4447777777, 4747777777, 4777777799, 4997777777, 5527777777, 5567777777, 6637777777, 6767777777, 7727777777, 7777777199, 7777777211, 7777777229, 7777777577, 7777777633, 7777777663, 7777777669, 7777777993, 8087777777, 8117777777, 8227777777, 8387777777, 8777777777, 8807777777, 9197777777, 9477777779, 9777777799, 9887777777, 9937777777, 9977777773]`

Comment: the bruteforce approach now is missing some too: you're finding them `[7777777019, 7777777027, 7777777057, 7777777069, 7777777081]`

Comment: Thanks, I change combinations in combinations_with_replacement. I don't take in account 9 digits solutions, so I have only 203.

Comment: thanks to you I found the missing ones in my formula too.

Comment: now both our answers yield the proper result. Good collaborative effort :)