# Generate prime numbers in a range of large digit number (numerals > 10 digits)

Tags: r, python-3.x, math, sympy, primes

I am trying to generate Prime numbers in ranges of large numbers (10 digits and above). But seems like whichever library I use it takes a infinite amount a time to generate them.

My code in R

```
library(numbers)
Primes(1000000000,9999999999)
```

My Code in Python

```
[i for i in primerange(1000000000,9999999999)]
```

Is there a better Library to generate these numbers quickly?

Comment: Generating prime numbers is a difficult math problem that takes computers a long time to solve in any method, that's why its useful in things like encryption. There's optimizations, but there's no easy way around the core difficulty

Comment: Do some more research.  There are even useful Qs and As on this topic here on SO (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326673/is-there-a-python-library-to-list-primes) and the Internet is awash with libraries, algorithms, implementations, even sites you can download lists of primes from.

Comment: Also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005608/finding-all-the-10-digit-prime-numbers-that-have-seven-7-in-a-row-python

Comment: According to oeis there are [404204977](https://oeis.org/A006879) primes with 10 digits. Just reading them from file would take some time.

Comment: Large prime numbers end in 1, 3, 7, 9.  You could generate 9 (or more) digits, append one of those four digits and test for primality.  There is a lot of information on prime testing available.

Comment: If you're generating many primes from a range, a variation on the sieve of eratosthenes is an efficient way to generalize the observation of @rossum to many more small primes.

Comment: What's your `sympy` setup code?

Comment: Thanks @JonanC, let me check this

Answer (score 0):

@JohanC makes a good observation. Do you really need all of the primes at once? Generating the "next" prime in this range is fast. If you can use 1 or a few at a time you could do

```
>>> p = nextprime(1000000000)
>>> while 1:
...     print(p)  # or do what you need to do
...     p = nextprime(p)
```

this shows

```
1000000007
1000000009
1000000021
...
```

If you don't want them to be successive (but don't mind the small likelyihood of repeating a value) you could use

```
while 1:
    p = nextprime(randint(1000000000,9999999999))
    # do something
```

Comment: How's this different from `primerange`?  `primerange` is a generator that uses `nextprime`.

Comment: `[i  for i in iterator]` will exhaust the iterator, a `while` loop allows you to do something with each output of the iterator as they are generated.